# ¿Se puede filtrar y mostrar un dato especifico de un documento anidado en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Tengo la duda de que si se puede realizar una consulta a un documento anidado extrayendo un dato en especifico, por ejemplo:
tengo la BD
`use Trabajadores`
y la coleccion `Usuario`. tengo la siguiente información:

```
{"Id": 45,"Nombre": "Javier", "Datos_Laborales": {"Trabajo": "Desarrollador", "Salario": 4585.00, "Empresa": "Microsoft"}}
```

Hora de mi documento quiero extraer solo el dato de la empresa en la que trabaja el usuario y mostrarlo como resultado. Tengo en mente lo siguiente:

```
db.Usuario.find({"Datos_Laborales.Empresa": "Microsoft"}, {"Datos_Laborales": {$slice: 1}}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero les sirva a alguien la respuesta al problema.
la solución esta modificando la consulta que se realizo, modificando los datos que se deben de mostrar usando la notación punto. quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
db.Usuario.find({"Datos_Laborales.Empresa": "Microsoft"}, {"Datos_Laborales.Empresa": 1}).pretty()
```